# Facing "Oh Snap!" Problem in the User Interface in React

Tags: reactjs, api, memory-leaks, snap

Facing this error in my react application
About Project - Just showing data that is being fetched by multiple apis
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RrFJ.png)

Tried checking for infinite loops in the project
Apart from that checked any memory leak but i can't find any

Expecting any reasons why is it happening as i have tried all the solutions that i have find across google.

Comment: Could you: check console for errors, supply code samples and describe your project functionality?

Comment: figured it out. Wasted days for looking the possible reasons. Forgot to use empty dependency in useEffect due to which it was taking a lot of js heap memory. Simple solution was to clear it using setInterval and clearInterval